# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 - clang error

Tags: c++, g++, clang, eclipse-cdt, openfst

Here's my sample code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fst/fst-decl.h>
#include <fst/fstlib.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace fst;

int main() {

    cout << "!!!Hello World!!! Yay!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    StdVectorFst fst;
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm compiling it using this command:

`g++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -v sampleFST.cpp;`

I'm using Google's openFST toolkit.

And upon running the command above I get the following error:

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? I've looked up this issue on google and the fix for this results in a `type_traits` error (it's like a vicious cycle).

Comment: Where do you link Google's openFST toolkit? See the [usage notes](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/pub/FST/FstDownload/README) for the library.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit at this directory - `usr/local/include/fst`

Comment: No, "linking" is something else.

Comment: `Link against /usr/local/lib/libfst.so and -ldl. Set your
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or equivalent) to contain /usr/local/lib` -- how do I "link against"? I'm sorry, I'm very very new to CPP!

Comment: @Saturnian: Consult the chapter in your book about how to build C++ projects with third-party dependencies.